# Constraint Propagation - how to handle ternary constraints going in the one-to-many direction

Tags: python, constraint-programming

I've implemented a framework to work through [SICP's propagation of constraints Celcius/Fahrenheit calculator example](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node65.html) (section 3.3.5 in the second edition of the book) in the following code:

```
import abc

import numpy as np


class Connector:
    """An object to store observable values."""

    def __init__(self):
        self._value = None
        self._informant = None
        self._constraints = []

    def has_value(self,):
        """Return true if connector has a value."""
        return self._informant is not None

    def get_value(self,):
        """Return connector value."""
        return self._value

    def set_value(self, new_value, informant='-USER-'):
        """Set value if none exists and inform constraints."""
        if not self.has_value():
            self._value = new_value
            self._informant = informant
            for constraint in reversed(self._constraints):
                if constraint != self._informant:
                    constraint.new_value()
        elif not np.array_equal(new_value, self._value):
            # Note: np needed as != is ambiguous on arrays.
            raise Contradiction("{} vs. {}".format(self._value, new_value))

    def forget_value(self, retractor='-USER-'):
        """Forget value and inform constraints."""
        if retractor == self._informant:
            self._informant = None
            for constraint in reversed(self._constraints):
                if constraint != retractor:
                    constraint.forget_value()

    def connect(self, new_constraint):
        """Add a new constraint."""
        if new_constraint not in self._constraints:
            self._constraints.append(new_constraint)
        if self.has_value():
            new_constraint.new_value()


class Constraint(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    """ABC for constraints among connectors."""

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def new_value(self,):
        """Notify constraint of a new connector value."""
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def forget_value(self,):
        """Notify constraint to forget all observed connector values."""
        pass


class Adder(Constraint):
    """Defines the constraint x + y == z"""

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.x.connect(self)
        self.y.connect(self)
        self.z.connect(self)

    def new_value(self,):
        if self.x.has_value() and self.y.has_value():
            self.z.set_value(self.x.get_value() + self.y.get_value(), self)
        elif self.x.has_value() and self.z.has_value():
            self.y.set_value(self.z.get_value() - self.x.get_value(), self)
        elif self.y.has_value() and self.z.has_value():
            self.x.set_value(self.z.get_value() - self.y.get_value(), self)

    def forget_value(self,):
        self.z.forget_value(self)
        self.x.forget_value(self)
        self.y.forget_value(self)
        self.new_value()


class Multiplier(Constraint):
    """Defines the constraint x * y == z."""

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.x.connect(self)
        self.y.connect(self)
        self.z.connect(self)

    def new_value(self,):
        if self.x.has_value() and self.y.has_value():
            self.z.set_value(self.x.get_value() * self.y.get_value(), self)
        elif self.x.has_value() and self.z.has_value():
            self.y.set_value(self.z.get_value() / self.x.get_value(), self)
        elif self.y.has_value() and self.z.has_value():
            self.x.set_value(self.z.get_value() / self.y.get_value(), self)

    def forget_value(self,):
        self.z.forget_value(self)
        self.x.forget_value(self)
        self.y.forget_value(self)
        self.new_value()


class Power(Constraint):
    """Defines the constraint x ** y == z."""

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.x.connect(self)
        self.y.connect(self)
        self.z.connect(self)

    def new_value(self,):
        if self.x.has_value() and self.y.has_value():
            self.z.set_value(self.x.get_value() ** self.y.get_value(), self)
        elif self.x.has_value() and self.z.has_value():
            self.y.set_value(np.log(self.z.get_value()) / np.log(self.x.get_value()), self)
        elif self.y.has_value() and self.z.has_value():
            self.x.set_value(self.z.get_value() ** (1.0 / self.y.get_value()), self)

    def forget_value(self,):
        self.z.forget_value(self)
        self.x.forget_value(self)
        self.y.forget_value(self)
        self.new_value()


class Equality(Constraint):
    """Defines the constraint x == y."""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.x.connect(self)
        self.y.connect(self)

    def new_value(self,):
        if self.x.has_value():
            self.y.set_value(self.x.get_value(), self)
        elif self.y.has_value():
            self.x.set_value(self.y.get_value(), self)

    def forget_value(self,):
        self.y.forget_value(self)
        self.x.forget_value(self)
        self.new_value()


class Constant(Constraint):
    """Defines the constraint x == value."""

    def __init__(self, x, value):
        x.connect(self)
        x.set_value(value, self)

    def new_value(self):
        raise Exception()

    def forget_value(self):
        raise Exception()


class Probe(Constraint):
    """Prints whenever connector has a new value."""

    def __init__(self, connector, name):
        self.name = name
        self.connector = connector
        self.connector.connect(self)

    def new_value(self,):
        self._print_probe(self.connector.get_value())

    def forget_value(self,):
        self._print_probe("?")

    def _print_probe(self, value):
        print("Probe: {} = {}".format(self.name, value))


class Contradiction(Exception):
    """Raised whenever a connector has an existing value but
    is asked to change a different value.

    """
    pass
```

The framework works fine replicating the Celcius/Fahrenheit example presented in SICP in both directions, as demonstrated in the below doctest:

```
>>> def celcius_fahrenheit_converter(c, f):
...     u = Connector()
...     v = Connector()
...     w = Connector()
...     x = Connector()
...     y = Connector()
...     Multiplier(c, w, u)
...     Multiplier(v, x, u)
...     Adder(v, y, f)
...     Constant(w, 9)
...     Constant(x, 5)
...     Constant(y, 32)

>>> c = Connector()
>>> f = Connector()
>>> celcius_fahrenheit_converter(c, f)
>>> c_probe = Probe(c, "Celcius temp")
>>> f_probe = Probe(f, "Fahrenheit temp")
>>> c.set_value(25.0)
Probe: Celcius temp = 25.0
Probe: Fahrenheit temp = 77.0
>>> f.set_value(212.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
Contradiction: 77.0 vs. 212.0
>>> c.forget_value()
Probe: Celcius temp = ?
Probe: Fahrenheit temp = ?
>>> f.set_value(212.0)
Probe: Fahrenheit temp = 212.0
Probe: Celcius temp = 100.0
```

When I attempted to use the framework to work through a physics problem (displacement vs. time given acceleration), I noticed that the "reverse" direction was not propagating in that network. I've determined that a simpler example (in this case, the quadratic equation y=ax**2+bx+c) exhibits the same behavior. It propagates fully if I try to solve for `y` given `x`, but not if I try to solve for `x` given `y`. See the below doctest (with internal connectors i1, i2 and i3 probed to illustrate the issue):

```
>>> def quadratic(a, b, c, x, y):
...     i0 = Connector()
...     i1 = Connector()
...     i2 = Connector()
...     i3 = Connector()
...     i4 = Connector()
...     i5 = Connector()
...     Equality(i0, y)
...     Adder(c, i1, i0)
...     Adder(i2, i3, i1)
...     Multiplier(b, x, i2)
...     Multiplier(a, i4, i3)
...     Power(x, i5, i4)
...     Constant(i5, 2.0)
...     Probe(i1, "i1")
...     Probe(i2, "i2")
...     Probe(i3, "i3")

>>> a, b, c, x, y = (Connector() for _ in range(5))
>>> quadratic(a, b, c, x, y)
>>> probe_x = Probe(x, "x")
>>> probe_y = Probe(y, "y")
>>> a.set_value(2.0)
>>> b.set_value(10.0)
>>> c.set_value(1.0)
>>> x.set_value(10.0)
Probe: x = 10.0
Probe: i3 = 200.0
Probe: i2 = 100.0
Probe: i1 = 300.0
Probe: y = 301.0
>>> y.get_value()
301.0
>>> x.forget_value()
Probe: x = ?
Probe: i3 = ?
Probe: i1 = ?
Probe: y = ?
Probe: i2 = ?
>>> y.set_value(301.0)
Probe: y = 301.0
Probe: i1 = 300.0
Probe: i2 = 100.0
Probe: i3 = 200.0
Probe: x = 10.0
```

Running the above doctest produces the following error when trying to propagate the constraints from `y` to `x`:

```
Failed example:
    y.set_value(301.0)
Expected:
    Probe: y = 301.0
    Probe: i1 = 300.0
    Probe: i2 = 100.0
    Probe: i3 = 200.0
    Probe: x = 10.0
Got:
    Probe: y = 301.0
    Probe: i1 = 300.0
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of  47 in __main__
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

What has happened is that when I told the network to forget the value of `x`, the `Adder` constraint that connects `i1`, `i2` and `i3` forgot all 3 values. So when the propagation returned in the `y` to `x` direction, the `Adder` found two unknowns (`i2` and `i3`, with `i1` following directly from `y` and `c`, which are known). This despite the fact that the equation only has one unknown (i.e. `x`), which unfortunately is influencing two of the three connectors found in the broken `Adder`.

**Question**

How do I repair either the design of the constraint network or the propagation algorithm to ensure that, in this simple quadratic example, I'm able to calculate both `y` given `x` **and** `x` given `y`?

**What have I tried**

I've attempted to research numeric constraint satisfaction algorithms but haven't found anything that seems applicable here.

I've tried to reason through redesigns of the constraint network itself so that `x` only connects to one constraint (which in this specific case could be the quadratic equation itself), but a) I can't get that to work in this example and b that doesn't seem like a general solution.

I've tried to reason through different constraint algorithms (e.g. search), but think that this may be overkill for a network defined completely with equality constraints.